# How to enable PKCE configuration for custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When we test user flows on PKCE enabled web applications, we get a drop down to configure the PKCE. But we do not get this when we try to test custom policies. Is there something we can do to enable this PKCE configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure on the dropdown you mentioned here specifically for PKCE. It would be great if you can share a screenshot of that for the reference. But regarding the use of PKCE, since PKCE is also a part of OAuth2.0 flows, hence the setup in custom policies would be same as that of any of the social media Claim Providers/Identity Providers. You can refer to the Facebook claim provider setup in our SocialAndLocalAccount policy from the starter pack for more information.

For reference: Sharing the extract for Github Claim Provider:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>github.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>GitHub</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="GitHub-OAuth2">
          <DisplayName>GitHub</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">github</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.github.com/user</Item>
            <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">user</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">GET</Item>
            <Item Key="UserAgentForClaimsExchange">CPIM-Basic/{tenant}/{policy}</Item>
            <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
            <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_GithubSecret"/>
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="numericUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
            <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserId" /> -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="github.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateIssuerUserId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>   
  </TechnicalProfiles>    
</ClaimsProvider>
```

If you check this sample you will find that there is an element called `<Protocol Name="OAuth2" />`, this enables support for OAuth2.0 protocol for this claims provider.